# Filtering punctuation in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I tried to extract all punctuation in this list ['!',';','?','...','<<','>>'] as follows:

```
my_data['My_Column'].str.findall(r'[?!.,?;...<<>>]*')
```

For instance

```
df['Test']
I really like Python!!
I don't like Gordon Ramsey...
He said: << I do not agree with you >>
```

Expected output:

```
df['Test']
[!!]
[...]
[<<,>>]
```

I'd appreciate if you can tell me how to fix my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try

```
df.Test.str.findall('[?!.<>]+')

0        [!!]
1       [...]
2    [<<, >>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
df.Test.str.findall(r'[?!.<>]+') 
Out[133]: 
0        [!!]
1       [...]
2    [<<, >>]
Name: Test, dtype: object
```